# Getting Element Not Interactable Exception after attempting to insert search query into YouTube input field

Tags: python, selenium

I'm just beginning to explore Python and automation testing
Wanted to create a quick script that will:

- Open a YouTube page
- Find the search input field where I will insert my search query
- Insert a search query into the field
- Press on the button to receive search results

Unfortunately Ive bumped into an error:
"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

Please assist

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

link = "https://www.youtube.com/"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get(link)

search_string = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input")

search_string.send_keys("Test search input")

button = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[3]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/button')

button.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of searching the `Input field` using the `absolute xpath` you can use the `id properties` of the element i.e `search` and similarly to click on the search icon to resolve the error.

**Note**:- We will have to specify the `input tag` along with the `id` since the page contains couple of element with `id as as search`

Your solution would look like

```
link = "https://www.youtube.com/"
browser.get(link)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#search").send_keys("Test 
search input")
button = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'search-icon-legacy')
button.click()
```

Comment: Hi @Владимир Придатко can you check the above solution